# Rails: how to test and access custom routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

so far in routes.rb

```
match 'campaigns_mobile_application', to: 'campaigns#update_mobile_store_application', via: [:post, :get]
```

in spec_helper.rb

```
config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

in controller_spec.rb

```
get campaigns_mobile_application_path format: :json # and here I have error
```

ok, I have error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError No route matches {:controller=>"campaigns", :action=>"/api/campaigns_mobile_application.json"}
```

change routes.rb now:

```
resources :campaigns do
  match 'mobile_application', to: 'campaigns#update_mobile_store_application', via: [:post, :get]
end
```

and also spec:

```
get campaign_mobile_application_path campaign_id: @campaign.id, format: :json
```

and again I catch error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"campaigns", :action=>"/api/campaigns/6775/mobile_application.json"}
```

How to fix this?

**UPD:**

I try different magic with `on: :member`, `on: :collection`, `as: :name` and other stuff.

Seems that I completely doesn't understand routing.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :campaigns do
  match :mobile_applications, to: 'campaigns#update_mobile_store_applications',
  via: [:post, :get], on: :member, as: :mobile_applications
end
```

**rake routes **

```
  mobile_applications_campaign POST|GET /api/campaigns/:id/mobile_applications(.:format)                             campaigns#update_mobile_store_applications
```

**controller.rb**

```
def update_mobile_store_applications
   render: json: { }, status: :ok
end
```

**spec.rb**

```
get mobile_applications_campaign_path campaign_id: @campaign.id, format: :json
```

generate error:

```
 Failure/Error: get mobile_applications_campaign_path campaign_id: @campaign.id, format: :json
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:action=>"update_mobile_store_applications", :controller=>"campaigns", :campaign_id=>8059, :format=>:json}
```

change request to this one (rename parameter):

```
get mobile_applications_campaign_path id: @campaign.id, format: :json
```

still generate error: ( different error )

```
 Failure/Error: get mobile_applications_campaign_path id: @campaign.id, format: :json
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"campaigns", :action=>"/api/campaigns/8108/mobile_applications.json"}
```

**UPD2**

This code works well on app but not in testing.

**UPD3**

This code works well on testing too now! Yeah!

```
get :update_mobile_store_applications, id: @campaign.id, format: :json
```

Comment: `get :mobile_applications_campaign_path, id: @campaign.id, format: :json` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
get :mobile_applications_campaign_path, id: @campaign.id, format: :json
```

The format was incorrect look here: https://github.com/everydayrails/rails-4-1-rspec-3-0/blob/master/spec/controllers/contacts_controller_spec.rb

This code is part of a [Everyday Rails Testing](http://everydayrails.com/) book, a very good book for learn testing with rspec on Rails

Comment: still doesn't work. `get mobile_application_campaign_path campaign_id: @campaign.id,format: :json` and `get mobile_application_campaign_path id: @campaign.id,format: :json` generate error: No routes match

Comment: can you make `rake routes` and paste the output

Comment: it seems that update_mobile_store_applications action doesn't exists in campaign controller, it's very strange